# light diffraction around dielectric vs around metal

Tags: optics, diffraction

trying to select a suitable material for the pinhole aperture of a pinhole camera. The pinhole minimum size is limited by diffraction. Is there a change in the quality/quantity of diffraction if the edge around which light diffracts is an electrical conductor or not ? (for ex in old polarizing filters the wires would interact with the electric field of the EM wave)

Answer (score 1):

If the material in which you make the pinhole is uniform on the sub-wavelength scale, and if the material completely absorbs (or reflects) the light that misses the pinhole, the performance of the pinhole will only depend on the shape and size of the pinhole.

Comment: if so then wire polarizers woulnt work, would they ?

Comment: A pinhole in a wire polarizer would not work the same as a pinhole in, say, aluminum foil.  I haven't tried making a pinhole in a wire polarizer, but my first guess is that it would act like an ordinary pinhole for the polarization component normally blocked by the wire polarizer, and would have almost no effect for the other polarization component.

Comment: I meant that if the material wasnt affecting the waves that pass near a conductor then wire polarizers wouldnt work (pinholes unrelated)

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You could ask this as a new question, and fill in the details, leaving out the pinhole part of the question.

Comment: do you agree that a wire polarizer changes the quality of the light (polarization)? Do you agree it does so because the wires in the polariser are conductors ? If so you'd agree that the light passing through the polarizer is affected by the proximity of the conductor. Therefore light is affected by the proximity of a conductor, therefore the pinhole material matters.....That's my reasonning

Comment: Sorry, I still do not fully understand your question.  Yes, a wire polarizer polarizes light that passes through it -- because the wires are conductors and because the wires are parallel, very thin, and very close together.  It is not clear, though, what you mean by "light is affected by the proximity of a conductor".  Light is certainly affected by a conductor if the light is incident on the conductor.

Comment: It is also not clear what you mean by "therefore the pinhole material matters".  Of course the pinhole material matters, if it is partly transmissive -- which a wire polarizer is.  If some light passes through the material in which the pinhole is punched, without going through the pinhole, it will not work very well as a pinhole filter.  A pinhole in a wire polarizer will filter one component of the polarization pretty well, but will not filter the other component well at all.

Comment: my understanding is that in a wire polarizer, the wires block incident light on the wire but also block light with a given polarity *between * wires (light having electric field parallel to the wires). Therefore I would expect light grazing the metal of the aperture of the pinhole to have some change to its polarity. I could imagine that if the pinhole is circular, all polarities are affected and therefore no change is visible, but if for instance the pinhole was elongated in a direction to form a slit, it would behave  like a polarizer if it was made of metal

Answer (score 1):

OK, now I see what you are asking.  You are imagining that some of the light hits the wires and some goes between the wires, and that the polarization filtering occurs only between the wires.  That's not the way it works.

Each photon is effectively much wider than the distance between the wires, so every photon that hits the wire grid polarizer "sees" the wires.  However, only the photons whose E vector is aligned with the wires can induce current in the wires and be absorbed.  For all practical purposes, photons whose E vector is perpendicular to the wires just go through as if the wires were not there. Essentially none of the photons whose E vector is parallel to the wires can get through, even though there *seems* to be space between the wires.

When a pinhole filter is used, it is typically at the focus of a lens, so a light beam is as small as it can be when it encounters the pinhole. Due to the geometry of the light beam and the lens, the beam waist is usually in the range from 5 to 40 microns in diameter, and the size of the pinhole is chosen to be slightly bigger than the beam waist.  The only portions of the beam that hit the material outside the pinhole are portions due to light that has been scattered upstream by, e.g., dirt on the optics.  The pinhole removes the scattered light, leaving a "clean" beam. So, light that gets through the pinhole basically never touches the material that the pinhole has been punched into.

As a result, if you make a pinhole in a wire grid polarizer and use the pinhole the way a pinhole is usually used, then most of the light, regardless of polarization, will go through the pinhole.  Scattered light, though, will hit the material of the wire grid polarizer.  The portion of the scattered light that has its E vector parallel to the wires in the grid will be absorbed.  The portion that has its E vector perpendicular to the wires will pass right through the wire grid polarizer.

In effect, a pinhole in a wire grid polarizer will act like an ordinary pinhole for light whose E vector is parallel to the wires, and will act like a sheet of glass for light whose E vector is perpendicular to the wires.

Comment: thanks for your answers:
-I do not intend to make a pinhole in the polarizer, I just use the polarizer as an example of how I believe a conductor material can affect the nature of light passing near (and the basis for my pinhole material selection question)
-"Each photon is effectively much wider than the distance between the wires" I believe photons have no width, but they have a wavelength.

Comment: -"Essentially none of the photons whose E vector is parallel to the wires can get through, even though there seems to be space between the wires" There is always space between the wires, otherwise no light would pass through. If there is space and yet only one polarization passes through, that means that the conductor of the wires *acts at a distance* on the light between the wires (assuming light having a position, which isnt quite so at that scale I know).  If the conductor acts at a distance between wires, then a conductor pinhole edge should act too on the light passing near the edge

Comment: You are right that light does not have a "position" at that scale.  The wavefunction of a photon in a beam focused on a pinhole is much larger than the spacing between wires in a wire grid polarizer.  IF a photon's wavefunction overlaps the edge of a pinhole, of course it will be influenced by the edge material.  But if there is no overlap, there will be no influence.